# on unload event blocks images from rendering?

Tags: javascript, onbeforeunload

I have the following scenario. When the user is about to leave the website I show him a confirmation message and at that moment I also modify the DOM a little bit. Despite the fact I get to modify the DOM, the images (even if they are preloaded will not appear).
I have also tried with Ajax but it looks as if during that moment all connections are blocked?

Here's my example code:

```
<div id="content">
    my original content...
</div>

<button id="trigger">click</button>

<script type="text/html" id="template">
    <div>
        <img src="/css/images/dmbtest.gif"/>
    </div>
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        window.onbeforeunload = function() {
            $('#content').html($('#template').html());
            window.onbeforeunload = null;
            return "some cool message";
        }
    });
</script>
```

Any suggestions? Would also love to be able to load the content via Ajax but... :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you rendered the #template HTML in a hidden div and instead of writing HTML to the #content onbeforeunload, you just show/hide the unload content you wish to display?

<s>I suspect that since the browser is essentially locked, it can't do the async writing like images that it needs to do.  If you show/hide, this async writing will already be done.</s>

Just a guess but I think that will work?

EDIT:  Oops.  I assumed your 'dont leave' notificaton was an alert, which would lock.  I realize now that that's not what you're doing, so ignore that bit :)

Comment: Switching between display:block/none or marging-top: -10000px/0px does actually work. What makes me wonder is that the images although I have preloaded them (confirmed via network tab in chrome) still will not be rendered when writing to the DOM whilst the DOM can actually be modified! But anyways, problem solved ;)

Comment: Interesting.  It may be some kind of tampering prevention.  Kinda like pages used to use onunload to not let you leave the page before browsers blocked such things.  I don't know why images would be involved in that but maybe.